# A long CGPath does not render

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, cgpath

I work with a spritekit engine and faced with the following problem. I need to draw a route on a map, for this I make an array of points, and create a path for the array with `CGPathAddLines` method. Everything worked fine until I tried to build a route between two distant points on the map. The path of it route not rendered.

I began to deal with the problem. I get the bounding box of my path with `CGPathGetBoundingBox` and I noticed that the route is not drawn each time width of it rect more than 2005 px. I know it sounds strange but in my case it really is. Below that part of the code which is used to create and display the path:

```
var pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable()    
let pathPoints = generatePathPoints()
CGPathAddLines(pathToDraw, nil, pathPoints, pathPoints.count)      

var shapeNode = SKShapeNode()
shapeNode.path = pathToDraw
shapeNode.lineWidth = 10
shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()

var effectNode = SKEffectNode()
effectNode.addChild(shapeNode)
mapNode.addChild(effectNode)
```

`generatePathPoints` - function return `[CGPoint]`

`mapNode` - object of `SKSpriteNode` type

Maybe I'm doing something wrong or is this a restriction of `CGPath` which I do not know?

Comment: "or is this a restriction of CGPath" Not of CGPath but perhaps of SKShapeNode. It is well known to have many unfortunate limits and you may have hit one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you tell some method to drawing a path without SKShapeNode?

Comment: You could just draw it into a layer or view, if only this were not a sprite kit situation. That makes it a lot harder. I suppose you could try drawing it into an image context and using the resulting image as a texture.

Comment: Thanks again, I will try to do so

Answer (score 0):

If it works well for short paths and then stops working for long ones, I'll assume (as @matt did) that it's because a limitation of SKShapeNode.

Have you tried creating more than one SKShapeNode with shorter paths and putting all of them inside another SKNode? With this solution you could work with the parent SKNode (full of smaller SKShapeNodes) as if it were your bigger SKShapeNode but (I hope) all the shorter paths will render correctly...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is not for my requirements, I need a way to be continuous and many SKShapeNodes are bad for performance

Comment: You could make them continuous by placing one `SKShapeNode` at the point where the previous `SKShapeNode` ended. And the bad performance is a bad side effect of this solution, yes, but at least it could help you finish your game while you find another solution... :)  So, I still believe this could be a good (temporary) solution.

Comment: I had already tried this option. And there are problems in addition to the performance. There is no a smooth transition between the lines that was created two differend `SKShapeNode`. It looks like this: http://imagehost.spark-media.ru/i4/70CE9B5B-D927-0A0C-BD65-A92F429F9221.png  It is necessary to add a separate node to connection point to fix the problem. But if it is one continuous path, all transitions are smooth automatically. And it will be looks like this: http://imagehost.spark-media.ru/i4/21605B3C-75B1-CCEC-1D3D-2A87DFB26441.png

Comment: Well, then do not start from the previous point but from two previous points and then I'd think they should appear properly connected... Anyway, if you have tried this and didn't find it a proper solution then I can't think of anything else but to wait for Apple to fix your problem (which, I know, doesn't help you at all, sorry). Maybe others have another solution?